# how to commit a pandas dataframe to JSON/utf-8 back to gitlab so it's read as a CSV

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv, gitlab

I can successfully read in a CSV like this using pandas and python-gitlab:

```
    filename = "file.csv"
    f = project.files.get(file_path=filename, ref='master')
    data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str(f.decode(),'utf-8')), sep=',', header=None, names=["direction", "width", "height"])
```

but I can't get the right structure back into json that is then read as a CSV by gitlab.

an example csv on gitlab file looks like this so you can see the structure

```
import csv, requests
from io import StringIO

url = "https://gitlab.com/datasets_a/mpg-data/-/raw/master/mpg.csv"
# Reading URL data
s = requests.get(url).content
# Decoding & formatting
data=csv.reader(StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
#Printing the first 5 rows
for row in list(data)[:5]:
    print(row)
```

and I can't just seem to convert the dataframe to json - here is my attempt!

```
def make_payload_commit(project, Time, filename, data):
        # payload
        data = {
                'branch': 'main',
                'commit_message': Time,
                'actions': [
                {
                        'action': 'update',
                        'file_path': filename,
                        'content': dataframe.to_json(),
                }
                ]
        }
        commit = project.commits.create(data)
```

gitlab doesn't register this as a CSV.

Would appreciate any help, if anyone knows how to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely, that your `.csv` file isn't recognised due to some encoding issues. To fix this, you can encode the file using Base64 encoding via [base64 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html).

Here is a working example how to upload the content of the file you provided to a selected repository using `pandas` and `github`:

```
import pandas as pd
import base64
import requests
import json

url = "https://gitlab.com/datasets_a/mpg-data/-/raw/master/mpg.csv"
# Reading URL data
data_orig = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

# Convert the DataFrame to a CSV string
csv_str = data_orig.to_csv(index=False)

# Encode the CSV string as base64
base64_content = base64.b64encode(csv_str.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer  <YOUR TOKEN>",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
}

# Create the request payload
payload = {
    "message": "add new csv file",
    "content": base64_content,
    "branch": "main"
}

# Convert the payload to JSON
json_payload = json.dumps(payload)

# Send the request to create the file
response = requests.put(<REQUEST GIT REPO URL>, headers=headers, data=json_payload)
```

The resulting file is uploaded to a toy repository [here](https://github.com/mcvincekova/python1_2023/blob/main/python_1/new1.csv).

---

You should be able to achieve the same via `gitlab` by setting the `encoding` attribute of the action to `base64` (see [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions)) like so:

```
data = {
        'branch': 'main',
        'commit_message': Time,
        'actions': [
        {
                'action': 'update',
                'file_path': filename,
                'content': base64_content,
                'encoding': 'base64'
        }
        ]
}
```

Hopefully, this helps.